# How can I cast an NSString as a hex representation of NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger

Cast is not the right word, but bear with me. I have the following string:

```
NSString *string = @"01700000";
```

However, I need to check if it contains a particular bit I'm looking for:

```
if (bitshift & (1 << 21)) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Getting the integer value by using `[string integerValue]` produces unexpected results:

```
NSInteger bitshift = (1 << 24) | (1 << 22) | (1 << 21) | (1 << 20);
NSString *flags = @"01700000";
NSInteger bitshiftString = [flags integerValue];

// bitshift: 1700000, bitshiftString: 19f0a0
NSLog(@"bitshift: %tx, bitshiftString: %tx", bitshift, bitshiftString);
```

What would be the most appropriate way to scan this string value into a `NSInteger`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is deliciously simple:

```
unsigned int bitshiftString;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:flags] scanHexInt:&bitshiftString];
```